# How to wait until mutex unlocked?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

There is an array of mutexes. 
My function:

1. Checks is a mutex is locked

2a. If not, then locks it

2b. If locked, wait for unlocking and locks it

Another function unlocks it.

The problem is that I got crash in the waiting section:

```
HANDLE mutexes[N];

void func(int i)
{
  // (*) wait until unlocked or create if unlocked
  while ((mutexes[i] = CreateMutex(NULL, TRUE/*same with FALSE*/, NULL)) != NULL);
  /*or WaitForSingleObject(mutexes[i], INFINITE)*/

  mutexes[i] = CreateMutex(NULL, TRUE, NULL);
}
```

At (*) point i got crash - access violation. Crash occurs when it's trying to create mutexes[i] which is already have been created previously. I can't use WaitForSingleObject because at first time mutexes[i] isn't created and docs says WaitForSingleObject is undefined. Also if i use this function i get the same crash.

All i need is the analog of such simple pseudocode

```
if (mutex_has_been_created[mutexes[i]])
  WaitUntilRelease()
CreateMutex();
```

I tried to wrap it in a critical section and got same result. I'm sure that `i` is within correct range.
I can't use Boost/pThreads/etc.

I know that my problem is quite easy, but i can't find the solution. In all examples i've seen a mutex is created before `WaitForSingleObject`, this doesn't work for me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You really need to sort out the logic of your code: the creation of mutexes and the locking/unlocking are distinct operations and should be treated as such. Frankly, all this business of "trying to create mutexes which already have been created" does not make a whole lot of sense.

Briefly:

1. [`CreateMutex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa914601.aspx) initializes ("creates") the mutex.
2. [`WaitForSingleObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb202783.aspx) et al lock the mutex (or time out).
3. [`ReleaseMutex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa908800.aspx) unlocks it.
4. [`CloseHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa914720.aspx) destroys it.

You create/destroy the mutex once and in between lock/unlock it as many times as you want.

When you try to lock a mutex that's already locked by someone else, your thread automatically blocks until the mutex becomes available.

Comment: I thought CreateMutex means lock it. I haven't found "LockMutex" function or something.

Comment: @fogbit: No, CreateMutex initializes the mutex. WaitForSingleObject locks it. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to wait until it is unlocked, only to lock it, then you can just lock it. That's exactly what happens when you do so. When you attempt a lock the code blocks until the mutex becomes available, and then locks it.

Comment: I don't know how to Lock it. I thought "to create mutex" means "to lock" it. If not, how can i lock it in winapi?

Comment: That's what `WaitForSingleObject` does.

Answer (score 1):

With posix threads you probably would use [condition variables](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConditionVariables); I have no idea if WinAPI offer similar things.

Answer (score 1):

```
HANDLE mutexes[N]

void InitMutexes(int N)
{
    for (int i =0; i < N ; i++)
    {           
        mutexes[i] = CreateMutex( NULL, FALSE, NULL);
    }
}
void WaitForMutex(int n)
{
    WaitForSingleObject(mutexes[n], INFINITE);
}
void ReleaseMutex(int n)
{
    ReleaseMutex(mutexes[n]);
}
void CleanUpMutexes(int N)
{
    for (int i=0; i < N; i++)
    {
          ReleaseMutex(mutexes[i]); CloseHandle(mutexes[i]);
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.